# next and previous JSON data with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I' would like to create Next/Previous buttons for json array, but I can't get it to work. 
This is the last one I have tried

```
 <div id="text"></div>
 <button name="prev">go to previous div</button>
<button name="next">go to next div</button>
 <script>

myFunction([
{
"text": "text0"
},
{
"text": "text1"
},
{
"text": "text2"
},
{
"text": "text3"
}
]);


function myFunction(arr) {
    var out = "";
    var i ;
    out = '<p>' +  arr[i].text + '</p> <br>';
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = out;
}
</script>
```

Comment: don't know what you want

Comment: like this example but with json array http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/1/

Comment: So why not start from that code and just change the divs for data? Your attempt above is not even similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can convert `json` data to `string` or better say `html` with `$.each` like below. as you tagged `jQuery`, here is `jQuery` approach:

```js
myFunction([{
    "text": "text0"
  },
  {
    "text": "text1"
  },
  {
    "text": "text2"
  },
  {
    "text": "text3"
  }
]);


function myFunction(arr) {

  $.each(arr, function(i, v) {
    $('#text').append('<div>' + v.text + '</div>');
  });

}
var divs = $('.mydivs>div');
var now = 0;
divs.hide().first().show();
$("button[name=next]").click(function(e) {
  divs.eq(now).hide();
  now = (now + 1 < divs.length) ? now + 1 : 0;
  divs.eq(now).show();
});
$("button[name=prev]").click(function(e) {
  divs.eq(now).hide();
  now = (now > 0) ? now - 1 : divs.length - 1;
  divs.eq(now).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text" class="mydivs"></div>
<button name="prev">go to previous div</button>
<button name="next">go to next div</button>
```

Comment: good job but i want to add button Next and button Previous as like
http://jsfiddle.net/WGkPV/716/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="text">
</div>
<script>
var i = 0;
let arr = [
{
"text": "text0"
},
{
"text": "text1"
},
{
"text": "text2"
},
{
"text": "text3"
}
];
setInterval(function myFunction() {
    var out = "";
    out = '<p>' +  arr[i].text + '</p> <br>';
    document.getElementById("text").innerHTML = out;
  console.log(out);
  if (i < arr.length - 1) {
    i += 1;
  } else {
    i = 0;
  }
}, 1000)
</script>
```